# How to create an image as a smaller scale of the present scene?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working on this ios app project with cocos2d, and I need to create an image that looks the same as the present scene but smaller, so I wonder if there's any way I can form an image directly from the scene with any functions?

Comment: You may have to define what "the present scene" is? Is it the camera's view? A picture from the camera? A video? A JPG file from the Internet?

Comment: The present scene is a CCLayer child class, and I want to convert it into a png so I can display it in other place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this link: [Cocos2d ScreenShot](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1722). It's a small extension to make a screen shot as a 2D texture.
After you just have to create a sprite with this texture and scale it down.

Comment: Thanks, I sort of found the same link.